# How do you make a Win10 Quick Access link to a symlink without it translating it to the original directory?

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link

Scenario:

1. Create SymLink: `C:\Data\workspaces --> C:\Users\****\Documents\workspaces`
2. Navigate to C:\Data\Workspaces in explorer
3. Click and drag the the path from the address bar onto "Quick Access" in the navigation pane.

Expected Result:

- Clicking on the shortcut takes you to `C:\Data\workspaces`

Actual Result:

- Clicking on the shortcut takes you to `C:\Users\****\Documents\workspaces`

How do you make it so that the shortcut points to the correct path. (the SymLink)

Command Used to create the SymLink:

```
mklink /D C:\Data\workspaces C:\Users\****\Documents\workspaces
```

***Updated with pictures:***

Please note the workspaces symlink inside C:\Data:

[image]

When I double-click on the symlink it works correctly. (note the address bar.

[image]

When i pin it to the Quick access bar, however, it uses the address that the symlink points to and NOT the symlink address.

[image]

Comment: Right click on document folder and change its location to your working folder. No need to create symlink.

Comment: Biswa - I didn't create the symlink to put it on the quicklist. This issue is that bookmarking the symlink url on the quicklist gets translated automatically to the referenced directory, which I don't want.

Comment: Symlinks are used so that programs assume the symlink as a actual folder but really they are pointed to elsewhere. So if you open that symlink in quick access explorer will open `C:\Users\****\Documents\workspaces` but really they are pointed to `C:\Data\workspaces`.

Comment: I know what it is for. You are misunderstanding the issue. When you go to a symlink, it will act as if the alias path is a real path even though it is not a real directory. However if you pin the symlink, it doesn't behave this way, it will take you to the liked path instead of the actual path. (it behaves like a shortcut instead of a symlink.)

Answer (score 2):

To prevent a symbolic link from being translated, you have to trick Windows by first pinning a regular folder to Quick Access, and then replacing it with a symbolic link.

```
mkdir symlink
```

then pin this to quick access using File explorer

```
rmdir symlink
mklink /d symlink "\\host\path\to\directory"
```

Partly copied from my blog: https://coertvonk.com/hw/logic/quartus-cycloneiv-de0nano-15932

Comment: This works beautifully. Note that you may need administrator privileges to run `mklink`. Open cmd by right clicking it and selecting "Run as Administrator".

Comment: You have to "rmdir symlink", not delete it in Explorer, or it won't work

Answer (score 0):

In mklink:

**/D** Creates a directory symbolic link.

**/J** Creates a Directory Junction.

[Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions) is the detail about the switches of mklink.

In your case, just replace /D with /J, for example:

```
mklink /J C:\Data\workspaces C:\Users\****\Documents\workspaces
```

This problem not only happened on Quick Access. For example, after you added a program as windows service, even the program path pointed to the link of symbolic link, the Service Manager still showing the target of symbolic in the service list.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your answer would be made better by explaining what this switch does and why it stopped the OP's problem.

Comment: You are right, thinks for your comment.

Comment: As soon as I'm able to test and verify this on Windows 10, I'll mark this as the solution.